# WHM upload CA root certificate to validate Cloudflare certificates

Tags: https, cpanel, security-certificate, cloudflare, whm

I'm using Cloudflare's self-signed certificates to encrypt traffic between Cloudflare and my origin web server.
A problem that cPanel shows a No Valid Certificate for the domain and the error SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN.
[image]

SSL/TLS Status shows as “Unknown Certificate Type”.

This posts ([1](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflares-origin-certificates-are-not-valid-certificates/287612), [2](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cpanel-shows-no-valid-certificate-for-installed-cloudflare-origin-ca/107439)) say Origin Certs are only recognized by Cloudflare for sites proxied by Cloudflare and host might need the Cloudflare Root CA ([Step 4](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/origin-ca#4-required-for-some-add-cloudflare-origin-ca-root-certificates)) to verify the cert on server... But I don’t know how to import an [CF RSA PEM](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/origin-ca#h_30cc332c-8f6e-42d8-9c59-6c1f06650639) key in WHM.
As far as I understand, this certificate should be displayed in SSL Storage Manager, but I do not know how to upload it from WHM.
I tried to upload an "origin_ca_rsa_root.pem" file manually to several server directories:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/etc/
/etc/ssl/certs
```

But it didn't help

Comment: Is this status affecting your website's ability to serve up the Origin certificate, or is it a warning you can ignore?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Yes, this problem partially affects site's ability. I am using WordPress and in this case I get a few errors because of this: 
1. REST API error. cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
2. Site could not complete a Loopback requests. Also cURL 60 error.

Comment: You can use `curl --insecure` to bypass the certificate checks when you run it against the WordPress API.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, but what about plugins that use curl? i can't change their code.  I found this controversial solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/12688835/5385052. but this seems to be a bad idea for a production site

Comment: What plugins are you using that call your own site via API?  Can you configure them to route API requests through Cloudflare (using your real domain name which has a valid cert)?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'm not using any plugin with Rest API. I just have a special plugin "Site Health" installed on my site that checks the system's functionality and gives this cURL error 60 warnings. And so everything works as it should

Answer (score 2):

When you are using a self-signed certificate, it is not supposed to be valid and it doesn't need to be valid.   The only client that needs to trust it is Cloudflare.  In fact, it might be desirable to use certificate on your origin server that isn't trusted by users as a way of discouraging access directly to your origin server.  In other words, this warning from WHM is expected and you can ignore it.

It is possible to make your web server trust that certificate.  However, importing Cloudflare's self-signing root certificate into your server's trust store will cause most programs that run on the server to trust ALL of Cloudflare's self-signed certificates.   Cloudflare issues these self-signed certs willy nilly and they are **not meant to be trusted**.   Trusting all Cloudflare self-signed certificates is a **security risk**.  It opens your web server up to man-in-the-middle attacks for every HTTPS request that your server makes.

If WHM won't serve your site with a self-signed certificate (I don't think that is actually the case), you have no choice but to add the root certificate to your trust store. [This page has instructions for installing root certificates for various operating systems and browsers](https://thomas-leister.de/en/how-to-import-ca-root-certificate/).  To install a new root certificate on a Linux server, you would use the commands:

```sh
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
sudo cp root.cert.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra/root.cert.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, I also found this post with tutorial how to install an additional cert on server https://superuser.com/a/719047

Comment: I found a solution for myself in which there is no need to add a certificate to the server. I am using Wordpress, as it turned out it uses its own certificate bundle in "wp-includes/certificates" folder in certs chain. So you can get rid of cURL error 60 by adding Cloudflare root certificate information to this file. I have only one question, how safe is it, can there be threats like a man in the middle or else?

Comment: That sounds fine to me.  You aren't changing it so that clients (like curl) trust certificates that aren't meant to be trusted.    It sounds like your plugin is trusting the wordpress cert for this request (and probably not for all requests.)